# ¿Que sucede con la reputación que excede el máximo diario?

Tags: soporte

Según [¿Que es la reputación?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) solo se obtiene un máximo de 200 diarios. Que sucede con los excedentes de reputación diaria? Se pierden o quedan en espera hasta el siguiente día?

Comment: El maximo diario se aplica a la reputacion que se obtiene mediante votos a favor y ediciones sugeridas. La reputacion obtenida por respuesta aceptada o recompensas no esta sujeta a la restriccion. No obstante, la reputacion que obtienes sobre los tags (los votos en tu perfil) no se ven afectados.

Comment: Esto lo podrás auditar fácilmente en http://es.stackoverflow.com/reputation. Allí verás cosas como _2  42536526 (10)_ (+1 en una respuesta) o _ 2  42536526 [0]_ (+1 en una respuesta, pero que ya no suma porque se alcanzaron los 200 diarios).

Answer (score 3):

Aunque lo que dice Rubén es cierto, para el máximo de la reputación diaria solo cuentan:

- Los votos a favor
- Edición de publicaciones (mientras que no tengas el privilegio [Editar Preguntas y Respuestas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit))

(hay más casos pero estos son los principales para ti)

Los puntos obtenidos por una respuesta aceptada o por una recompensa no están afectos al límite diario de 200 puntos de reputación. Es decir, puedes responder muchas preguntas que sean aceptadas y sobrepasar los 200 puntos del día.

Para más información, revisar [How does reputation work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7237/182862)

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta directa a esta pregunta, en realidad es muy corta,

se pierden.

Es muy fácil de comprobar, sólo espera un día.

Comment: :( entonces no responderé nada mas por hoy :P jajaja

Comment: Esa es la idea, déjale algo a los demás XD

Comment: ajaja Si no soy tan [fanatico](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/55/fanatic) pero a veces estoy entusiasmado :P